# R How can I place the values of a second column under the values in the left column?

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns

I have the following function with which I want to create summary statistics (for two data sets simultaneously):

```
mean.k <-function(x){round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), digits = 3)}
sd.k <-function(x){round(sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), digits = 3)}

sumstats<-function(x, y) { sumtable <- cbind(as.matrix(colSums(!is.na(x))),sapply(x,mean.k), paste("(",sapply(x,sd.k),")", sep = ""), as.matrix(colSums(!is.na(y))),sapply(y,mean.k), paste("(",sapply(y,sd.k),")", sep = ""))
sumtable=as.data.frame(sumtable)
names(sumtable)=c("Obs","Mean","Std.Dev", "Obs","Mean","Std.Dev");
sumtable}
```

On some data, the result looks like:

```
data(iris)
libary(dplyr)
iris_1 <- iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) # data set 1 
iris_2 <- iris %>% filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) # data set 2
iris_desk_stats <- sumstats(iris_1, iris_2)
```

[image: Result from function so far]

However, for me the optimal result would look like this:

[image: Optimal result]

So the two changes I need are the following:

- Each standard deviation should be placed under the respective mean instead of in a separate column next to the means.
- Obs should not be a proper column, but a row at the top in order to avoid redundancy.

Has anyone an idea? The first of the two desired changes would be the most important one.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I'd try to approach this "directly"; And here's what I've come up with:

```r
iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  summarise(
    across(!where(is.factor), list(
      mean = . %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE),
      sd = . %>% sd(na.rm = TRUE)
    )),
    Obs = n()
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    # c(contains(c("mean", "sd")), "Obs"),
    everything(),
    names_to = c("variable", "metric"),
    values_to = "stats",
    names_sep = "_") %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(metric = "identity")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = metric,
              values_from = stats) %>%
  
  select(variable, everything()) %>% 
  mutate(entries = glue::glue("{mean}<br>({sd})",
                              mean = round(mean, 3),
                              sd = round(sd, 3)),
         entries = if_else(!is.na(identity), 
                           glue::glue("{identity}"), 
                           entries)) %>% 
  select(-c("mean", "sd", "identity")) %>%
  arrange(variable) %>% 
  
  gt::gt() %>% 
  gt::fmt_markdown(entries) %>%
  identity()
```

[image: output from gt]

Comment: @ Mossa, thank you very much for this idea! When running the code, I get the following message: "Warning message: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [9]. "At which place are 2 pieces expected? In the iris data, there are no missing pieces. Or does it expect two data sets like in my example? But I don't see I could put in two data sets in your code. Also, when trying to export to Excel, in the .xlsx file, the lines look like this: "Petal.Width <div class='gt_from_md'><p>1.199<br>(0.762 </p> </div>". Is there a way to export it to Excel like the table in the Viewer?

Comment: the warning comes from trying to pivot "Obs", as it is not like `mean` and `sd` transformations. So don't worry too much about that.

Comment: I used `<br>` to make it a markdown line-break.. Because that just works sometimes. For excel, I think you need to replace `<br>` with `\n` or even `\n\r`. Please try that out.

Comment: I have tried both versions and they yield the same result as the basic version. Strangely, in Excel, I get a bunch of different sheets with the same entries in each sheet (named e.g. _data, _boxhead, _stub_df, _row_groups, _heading,....)

Comment: Yeah, you're not supposed to use `gt` for this at all. Remove that part, and just export the result prior to `gt` call; Then use the changes.

Comment: I don't have Excel on my home machine, so I cannot help further :(